# Cleverf and hyperlink when resetting chapter counter

Tags: cleveref, hyperlink, setcounter

I am writing a dissertation and I need it to be in two languages (English and Spanish).

The organization is as follows:

1. Table of contents
2. Preface and Abstract appear in both languages
3. Body of the dissertation: first, all the chapters appear in english (in part 1) and then all the chapters in Spanish (in part 2). The content of part 1 and part 2 is the same but translated. So, I decided to reset page numbering and chapter numbering when transitioning from Part 1 to Part 2.

I use both `cleverer` and `hyperlink` packages (this is a must).

Below, you can find a simplified version of the template utilized for the dissertation:

```
\documentclass[12pt, footinclude=true,headinclude=true,  twoside=semi,  headsepline=true, chapterprefix=false, appendixprefix=true, headings=big, numbers=enddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english, spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% MWE 21June16
% COMMENTS: Resetting chapter counter to 0 for each new part.
%=========================================
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalise,nameinlink]{cleveref}

% Or
% \usepackage{chngcntr}
% \counterwithin{chapter}{part}

\begin{document}
%===========
\frontmatter
%===========
\selectlanguage{english}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface/Prefacio}
.... some text ....

\chapter{Abstract/Resumen}
.... some text ....
%===========
\mainmatter
%===========

\part*{English version}

\chapter{English}\label{chapter1EN}
This is \Cref{chapter1EN}.


\chapter{English}\label{chapter2EN}
This is \Cref{chapter2EN}.


\chapter{English}\label{chapter3EN}
This is \Cref{chapter3EN}.


\chapter{English}\label{chapter4EN}
This is \Cref{chapter4EN}.


\selectlanguage{spanish}
\newpage
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\part*{Spanish version}
\chapter{Spanish}\label{chapter1ES}
This is \Cref{chapter1ES}.

\chapter{Spanish}\label{chapter2ES}
This is \Cref{chapter2ES}.

\chapter{Spanish}\label{chapter3ES}
This is \Cref{chapter3ES}.

\chapter{Spanish}\label{chapter4ES}
This is \Cref{chapter4ES}.

\end{document}
```

The issue is that all the references also "reset" and when clicking the link corresponding to `label=chapter1ES` in both the text (in the portion of text corresponding to `\Cref{chapter1ES}`) and in the TOC it refers to `label=chapter1EN`.

Is there any way of resetting the page numbering and the chapter counter without affecting the labels and their references?

Comment: consider if this is really a good idea to repeat page numbers. E.g. try to print page 7. Which one will you get?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have distinct pages with the same number.

Disabling `hypertexnames` should cure the problem.

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  footinclude=true,
  headinclude=true,
  twoside=semi,
  headsepline=true,
  chapterprefix=false,
  appendixprefix=true,
  headings=big,
  numbers=enddot
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english, spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <--- needed for Spanish
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % <--- no longer needed

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalise,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

%===========
\frontmatter
%===========
\selectlanguage{english}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Preface/Prefacio}
.... some text ....

\chapter{Abstract/Resumen}
.... some text ....

%===========
\mainmatter
%===========

\part*{English version}

\chapter{English}\label{chapter1EN}
This is \Cref{chapter1EN}.


\chapter{English}\label{chapter2EN}
This is \Cref{chapter2EN}.


\chapter{English}\label{chapter3EN}
This is \Cref{chapter3EN}.


\chapter{English}\label{chapter4EN}
This is \Cref{chapter4EN}.

\cleardoublepage
\selectlanguage{spanish}

\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\part*{Spanish version}

\chapter{Spanish}\label{chapter1ES}
This is \Cref{chapter1ES}.

\chapter{Spanish}\label{chapter2ES}
This is \Cref{chapter2ES}.

\chapter{Spanish}\label{chapter3ES}
This is \Cref{chapter3ES}.

\chapter{Spanish}\label{chapter4ES}
This is \Cref{chapter4ES}.

\end{document}
```

Look at the comments at the beginning about packages. I'm not sure about using both `shorttoc` and `etoc`, though.